# iOS 8 MDM: managed app configuration doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios8, mdm

In our custom mobile device management (MDM) solution we use [managed app configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html):

- MDM server pushes InstallApplication payload with Configuration dictionary.
- The app uses `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"com.apple.configuration.managed"];`

Everything worked fine.

Due to changes in iOS 8.1.3 we resigned the application as it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195564/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-install-on-ios-8-1-3). After that the app can be installed and it launches well on iOS 8.1.3+. But it **cannot read the configuration using NSUserDefaults** (configuration data from MDM server is not set).

In logs I see this warning:

> profiled[128] : *** -[NSXPCConnection valueForEntitlement:]: Error getting value for entitlement 'com.apple.managedconfiguration.profiled-access': Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (POSIX error -1 - Unknown error: -1)"

I guess this warning describes the reason of the problem. But what does that message mean?

I also tried to add `com.apple.managedconfiguration.profiled-access` key with `true` value to entitlements when signing the app, but it ended up with the error:

> installd[420] : 0x41d000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]: 188: Failed to verify code signature of  : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)

Comment: did you find a solution?Please share if you did.Thanx :)

Comment: Enable Push Notifications in the Entitlements. Unfortunately I still can't see the dict so this isn't the final answer, just a step that those errors are hinting to you. I'm still debugging this myself, will post an answer if I find it