# Mobile Iron MDM compatibility for iOS and Android app preferences

Tags: android, ios, nsuserdefaults, mobileiron

I developed a mobile app for `iOS` and `Android`.  A customer wants to use this app for their employees and their company uses `Mobile Iron MDM` to manage all employee devices.  There is a preference setting (web service URL) in the app that the customer wants to be able to manage through their Mobile Iron.

My question is, is there anything specific that needs to be configured or changed in my iOS and Android apps so they are compatible with Mobile Iron MDM?  Specifically, to allow Mobile Iron to manage the user settings.

I've never used Mobile Iron or any MDM before so I don't know how this works.  I've looked at the [Mobile Iron site](http://www.mobileiron.com) for information but it appears you need to be a partner to access a lot if the technical information.

I've found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752254/using-mdm-to-configure-an-enterprise-app-via-nsuserdefaults) about iOS and MDM and it mentions `NSUserDefaults` but I'm not sure if this is what I should be looking for.

Comment: Reach out and ask them. If the information you're looking for is available only to partners, then they're likely bound by NDA. If not, ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Mobile Iron **AppConnect** to accept app-specific configurations.  Then Administrators can configure the settings for your app.  To prepare your app for this, Mobile Iron provides sample `iOS` and `Android` projects that show exactly how to do this.  The samples show the functions you need to use but you need to become a **Mobile Iron partner** to access this information.

[Here](https://www.mobileiron.com/en/datasheet/appconnect-and-apptunnel-datasheet) is more information on AppConnect

Comment: Can someone explain why this would get a down vote?  If it needed a down vote that's great but I just want to understand how to write better answers, I don't see what's wrong here.  My question was about how to use MobileIron to manage app preferences and I think this answer explains how to do that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello  Thanks.  In addition to the link, I point to the sample `iOS` and `Android` projects that Mobile Iron provides when you are a Partner member.  Those projects have the specific functions you need to add this capability to your app.  I would have put the actual code here but they only share it with Partner program Members so I didn't know if that was appropriate.  For anyone looking how to do this, follow my answer after becoming a member and you can see the app samples from Mobile Iron.

Comment: Even pointing out that you need to look at Mobile Iron **App Connect** specifically is very helpful for anyone looking to do this.  It took me days to find this out and there aren't any other questions on stack overflow addressing this.

Comment: @Heinrich how do you become a member ?