# how to send data from airwatch to ios app

Tags: ios, mdm, airwatch

I'm a junior ios developper trying to communicate with the MDM server : air watch.
I found lot of topics talking about getting the data from the MDM server in my app (like [Using MDM To Configure An Enterprise App Via NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752254/using-mdm-to-configure-an-enterprise-app-via-nsuserdefaults) and https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T224565) but I cannot find any tutorials on how air watch send data to ios app.

Does anybody face the same problem or have links to help me get through ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

This will work: [AppConfig](https://www.appconfig.org/)

Implementation in iOS is much simpler than Android

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what data you want to send down to the app, but syncing application data is usually not the domain of an MDM/EMM solution.  I would use either use  Apple APNS to publish to the app (directly or through a 3rd party provider) or use periodic polling initiated from your app to fetch you data. A common pattern is to publish a small payload to the app (e.g key-oriented data) and then let it fetch the real application payload using the Apple networking stack

If you use APNS and your enterprise is averse to opening your network to the internet (very common),  consider a 3rd party provider like UrbanAirship, Azure,... They handle the initial token handshake as well as provide nice group messaging and other features. Good luck.

Comment: Hi JiOS - if this answered your question can you select it or please post additional detail if you need it?

Comment: Hi Dave !  Sorry for my late reply and thank you for your answer ! :)
I was hoping to use airwatch to configure app via NSUserDefaults.
I'll try your solution next time and i'll be faster to answer !