# How to read "com.apple.configuration.managed" Using MDM To Configure An Enterprise App Via UserDefaults - Swift 3 or 4

Tags: ios, configure, enterprise, mdm, managed

```
let serverConfig = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed") print("serverConfig count:
\(String(describing: serverConfig?.count))")
```

> Above code always returning **nil** for iOS 11 and above. but same
>   code is working for me on iOS 9,10.

I have checked this ref [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752254/using-mdm-to-configure-an-enterprise-app-via-nsuserdefaults) code but somehow it's not working fine for me.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.