# Notify In my App when other apps installed or removed in same iOS device using MDM

Tags: ios, swift3, enterprise, mdm, apple-configurator

I want **get notifire** or any type of observer in my app when **any other app installed or removed** in same device(iPhone/ipad) using MDM.

Just like **Outpact app**

I just try it in device which has MDM certificated Installed.
But getting Nil response

```
  let managedConf = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed") as? [String:Any?] 


Output : nil
```

I also try NotificationDidChange  but it is also not working

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: { note in

            print(note.object)

    })
```

Also checked  this [Using MDM To Configure An Enterprise App Via NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752254/using-mdm-to-configure-an-enterprise-app-via-nsuserdefaults)
 but not getting result

Please help me or suggestion any idea about it.

Thanks

Comment: The MDM server can get the app inventory for a device. An app running on the device cannot